Elastic Serverless Forwarder Deployment Is Failing
Deploying elastic serverless forwarder through cloudformation. My first deployment is working fine but everytime I try to create second application is fail due to below error:
MacroElasticServerlessForwarder is failing as elastic serverless forwarder macro alreday exists.

Looks a lot like this: https://github.com/elastic/elastic-serverless-forwarder/issues/322
